# How can I combine 2 images using a 3rd alpha mask image

Tags: c#, image, mono

I have 2 images, foreground and background.  I want to combine the 2 using an alpha mask image such that black = use background pixel, white = use foreground pixel and grey is an alpha blended mix of the 2.

The foreground and background images are fixed, while the mask image is created on the fly and then moved as required to create an animation.

Is there any performant way to do this using the standard library?  I can use LockBits and a loop but I'd like something faster, if such a thing exists.